# Need dynamic conditional search fields for advanced search for users

Tags: search

I need a field that will drop down according to first choice, for example:

Region:
 - USA
   - California
   - Florida
 - Canada
  - Quebec
  - Ontario

So if USA is selected, then states will be next, if Canada is selected, then provinces will be next.

Something like here:

http://www.vincentmoving.com/chain/chainedmenu.html

or even better:

http://www.pof.com/basicsearch.aspx

I've tried hierarchal_select, conditional_fields and exposed_filters.

Any solution possible for this?